# Django selected value using manual render form in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to implement CRUD operations in django, however, I'm stuck in the edit operation.
After passing the data to edit template I need to show the selected values of operating system dropdown list, how can I achieve that?
I utilized the manual rendering of django form with the following code in the template:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Operating System</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control" name="os_id" id="os_id" required>
                          <option value="">--Select--</option>

                        {% for os in os %}
                            <option value="{{ os.id}}">{{ os.key_name}}</option>                       
                        {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

   <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Title</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="title" name="title" rows="3" required>{{ servicedesk.title }}</textarea>
                  </div>
                  </div>
```

here's the view code:

```
def edit(request, id):
    servicedesk=Servicedesk.objects.get(id=id)
    softwares=Software.objects.all      
    os=OperatingSystem.objects.all 
    context = {'servicedesk':servicedesk, "softwares":softwares, "os":os}
    return render(request, 'servicedesks/edit.html', context)
```

and the model:

```
class OperatingSystem(models.Model):
    key_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True) 
    key_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True) 
 
    class Meta:  
        db_table = "operating_systems" 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key_name

class Software(models.Model):
    key_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True) 
    key_description = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True) 
 
    class Meta:  
        db_table = "softwares" 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key_name        

class Servicedesk(models.Model):  
    os_id=models.ForeignKey(OperatingSystem, on_delete=models.SET(0))
    software_id = models.ForeignKey(Software, on_delete=models.SET(0))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
```

I tried this but it's not working:

```
    <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Operating System {{os_id}}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control" name="os_id" id="os_id" required>
                          <option value="">--Select--</option>

                        {% for os in os %}
                            {% if os.id == servicedesk.os_id %}                        
                            <option value="{{os.id}}" selected>{{os.key_name}}</option>
                            {% endif %}
                            <option value="{{ os.id}}">{{ os.key_name}}</option>                       
                        {% endfor %}
                          </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use `UpdateView` which is a class based view that django provided. It does a lot of job for you.

Comment: will check on this. Thank you very much.